# Rails 7.1 resolve conflicting Zeitwerk Inflection rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, rails-engines, zeitwerk, inflector

I have a Rails 7.1 app and multiple (Rails Engine) Gems with conflicting inflection rules.
There is `Gem1::Api::Gem1Controller` under `app/controllers/gem1/api/gem1_controller.rb`
and `Gem2::API::Gem2Controller` under `app/controllers/gem2/api/gem2_controller.rb`.
As I understand it, Zeitwerk uses global autoloaders for the whole Rails app including all Rails Engines (which are more or less treated as part of the main app).

By default, Zeitwerk can load `Gem1::Api::Gem1Controller`, but fails to load `Gem2::API::Gem2Controller`, because the inflection rule for `"api" => "API"` is missing.

However, using the "normal" approach of adding custom inflection rules will not work, since then it will fail to load `Gem1::Api::Gem1Controller` because it expects to find `Gem1::API::Gem1Controller`.

```
# config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb
Rails.application.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
  autoloader.inflector.inflect("api" => "API") # works for Gem2, but breaks Gem1 as a result
end
```

Is there any way to define inflection rules that include the whole namespace? Something like

```
# config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb
Rails.application.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
  autoloader.inflector.inflect("gem2/api/gem2_controller" => "Gem2::API::Gem2Controller")
end
```

Or maybe there is a way to define a per-Gem or per-Rails-Engine inflector? Keep in mind it still needs to work as a Rails Engine.

Comment: Sadly that does not work, neither with the inflection `"api" => "API"` nor without. The result is always uninitialized constant.

Comment: "Zeitwerk uses global autoloaders for the whole Rails app including all Rails Engines". Let me rephrase that to be more exact: Rails configures just two loaders, and they manage the application and all engines too. The root problem diagnose is correct, and the custom inflector the way to go. In this was day 0 in Rails, maybe we could have different loaders per engine, but this was not possible with classic and we have inherited this design, so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem via a custom Inflector. The regular `Rails::Autoloader::Inflector#camelize` ignores its second argument, but incorporating the absolute filepath into the camelization enables me to use both `Gem1::Api` and `Gem2::API`.

```
# config/initializers/autoloaders.rb
module PathnameSuffixInflector
  @overrides = {}
  @max_overrides_depth = 0

  def self.camelize(basename, abspath)
    return @overrides[[basename]] || basename.camelize if @max_overrides_depth <= 1

    filenames = Pathname.new(abspath).each_filename.to_a[0..-2] + [basename]
    @max_overrides_depth.downto(1).each do |suffix_length|
      suffix = filenames.last(suffix_length)
      return @overrides[suffix] if @overrides.key?(suffix)
    end

    return basename.camelize
  end

  def self.inflect(overrides)
    @overrides.merge!(overrides.transform_keys { Pathname.new(_1).each_filename.to_a })
    @max_overrides_depth = @overrides.keys.map(&:length).max || 0
  end
end
PathnameSuffixInflector.inflect("gem2/api" => "API")

Rails.application.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
  autoloader.inflector = PathnameSuffixInflector
end
```